# how to compute the average, write it to a CSV file then sort it using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get my function to work out the average, write it to a file and sort it using python. This is my code:

```
def average_score(filename):

    with open(filename) as Class:
        reader = c.reader(Class,delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            people = []
            people.append(row[0])
            user, *scores = row
            average = sum([int(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)
            a = open(filename,"a").writer(Class)

            data = [[average]]

            a.writerows(data)
            people.append(score)

            count = count+1
            list11.insert(count,people)

    sort=sorted(list11, key = o.itemgetter(4), reverse = False)
    for eachline in sort:
        print( eachline)
```

csv file:

```
kieran,3,10,7
ben,4,8,5
ethan,9,1,4
oliver,7,2,3
```

Comment: do u want to sort them by score or by avarages? I don't get it

Comment: by their averages any way possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
def average_score(filename):

    averages = {}
    with open(filename) as fd:
      reader = c.reader(fd, delimiter=",")

      for row in reader:
        user, *scores = row

        # the user has no score
        if len(scores) == 0:
           continue

        averages[user] = sum([int(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)

    sorted_averages = sorted(averages.items(), key = o.itemgetter(1), reverse = False)

    # This writes the average to the file, remove if necessary
    with open(filename, 'a') as fd:
      for item in sorted_averages:
        fd.write("{}: {}\n".format(item[0], item[1]))

    # This prints out to screen, remove if necessary
    for item in sorted_averages:
        print("{}: {}".format(item[0], item[1]))
```

Comment: thanks but it said     for user, avarage in sorted_avarages.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
>>>

Comment: sorry, please test the last version

Comment: cheers mate that's fantastic but is it possible to print the scores then delete them so it doesn't interfere with other programs

Comment: what do you mean? sorry not clear, delete them from where?

Comment: print the averages on the console then delete them from the csv if possible

Comment: I am not sure I got you correctly, anyway now you have both the code to write to file and to write to console. Remove what you don't need.

Comment: thanks i get this error averages[user] = sum([int(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Comment: That happens because you have any users with no score. I will make a small fix for that

Comment: Thanks have been stuck on this for ages